# Why is the quality filter for questions and answers so poor?

Tags: discussion

Supposedly there are spam filters on this site. How do answers like this one get through?

[Accept current job offer or wait for future offer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/154306/accept-current-job-offer-or-wait-for-future-offer/154324#154324)

If nothing else, it should be flagged for having no content beyond a repeated string.

Comment: Per my understanding Stack's own filters are pretty basic/poor. There is SmokeDetector, a community project, that is better but it works by a) being modified on new cases (should catch repeated strong/few unique characters already) and b) users flagging the post as spam and/or rude/abusive (as well as "automatic" flags if above a threshold) so it is only a post-posting measure that aims to speed things up.

Comment: @TheLethalCompany That's my understanding as well. In this instance that question was flagged by SmokeDetector immediately and it subsequently got 5 confirmation flags as spam/rude within 15 minutes with the fifth confirming the deletion. Beyond that we can't really comment further on the automated processes in place. The position of SmokeDetector as a community project rather than an official SE one can be debated but I suspect it already has been on main meta.

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to debate about SmokeDetector... it was created by users who care about quality content on the Stack Exchange network, because SE Inc. wasn't interested in ensuring that quality. The new management might be interested in changing that but I wouldn't hold my breath.